# Trigger Test Class

Tags: trigger

I have a simple trigger but enable to cover the code coverage please anyone idea about this?

```
trigger ClosedOpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (before insert) 
{   
    list<task> carry = new list<task>();
    for(opportunity opp: trigger.new)
    {
        if(opp.StageName == 'Closed Won')
        {
           task t = new task(whatid=opp.id,Subject = 'Follow Up Test Task');
            carry.add(t); 
        }
   }
     insert carry;
}
```

**Here is My test class**

```
@isTest
public class TestOppTrig 
{
    static testmethod void testFun()
    {
        Opportunity opp = new opportunity();
        opp.Name = 'Bob';
        opp.StageName = 'closed won';
        opp.CloseDate = system.today();
        insert opp


        task t = new task();
        t.whatid=opp.id;
        t.subject = 'dasfsdfds';
        insert t;
    }
}
```

Here is the Screen Shot

[image]

Comment: Here is the screen shot

Comment: Please Take a Look.

Comment: Hi Ratan Thanks for help.I will sort out this problem with my end

Comment: Bonny Sure.. Let me know once it works or any other issue you face. Thanks

Comment: Hi Ratan. It was my mistake Code was right but i inactive that trigger that's why its passed the method but did not show coverage.

Comment: Bonny Now it is working ?

Comment: Yes its cover 100 percentage also changed BEFORE to AFTER in trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trigger should be on after insert.. Because in before context we don't get opp Id

Since you trigger on opportunity before insert you need to insert opportunity

`insert opp;` this will fire your trigger

JUst insert opportunity. then your trigger will create a Task record.

So put **System.assertEquals** to check if there is any task created on opportunity or not

```
@isTest
public class TestOppTrig 
{
    static testmethod void testFun()
    {
        Opportunity opp = new opportunity();
        opp.Name = 'Bob';
        opp.StageName = 'closed won';
        opp.CloseDate = system.today();
        insert opp;
        System.assertEquals([SELECT Id FROM Task WHERE whatid =: opp.Id].size(), 1);
    }
}
```

---

In you developer console. You need to check **Run as Asynchronous** checkbox and then run your test class

[image]

Comment: I add "insert" statement but it also show 0 percentage coverage.

Comment: @Bonny are you running test class in developer console. If yes you need to check **run as Asynchronous** checkbox

Comment: Hello Ratan its Shows the test method is pass but not shown the code coverage.

Comment: @Bonny check my updated Ans.. If that won't work then I suggest run your test class from any IDE

Comment: Hi Ratan thanks for assisting i did the same as you told but i did not show the any code coverage

Answer (score 0):

You have your trigger on opportunity so insert opportunity in your test class.

```
@isTest
public class TestOppTrig 
{
    static testmethod void testFun()
    {
        Opportunity opp = new opportunity();
        opp.Name = 'Bob';
        opp.StageName = 'closed won';
        opp.CloseDate = system.today();

       insert opp;
    }
}
```